# Symfony 4 entity getters return types

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, return-type, php-7.1

I'm currently using **Symfony 4.1 on PHP 7.1 with Sonata Admin** and there is a little problem with entity getters return types... Since I know which fields are nullable, I can set mandatory or optional return type. But this aproach doesn't work when I'm binding entity on the create form of sonata admin, because entity is not initialized and all fields are set to null. Solution is obvious, but which is more correct?

**Solution 1:**
Make return type optional (nullable)

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Table(name="banner__banner_zone_relation")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class BannerZoneRelation implements TimestampableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Banner
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Banner\Banner", inversedBy="bannerZoneRelations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $banner;

    /**
     * @var Zone
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Banner\Banner",inversedBy="bannerZoneRelations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $zone;

    /
    /**
     * @return Banner|null
     */
    public function getBanner(): ?Banner
    {
        return $this->banner;
    }

    /**
     * @return Zone|null
     */
    public function getZone(): ?Zone
    {
        return $this->zone;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**
Creating instance of Banner and Zone in constructor

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Table(name="banner__banner_zone_relation")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class BannerZoneRelation implements TimestampableInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Banner
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Banner\Banner", inversedBy="bannerZoneRelations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="banner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $banner;

    /**
     * @var Zone
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Banner\Banner",inversedBy="bannerZoneRelations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="zone_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $zone;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->banner = new Banner();
        $this->zone = new Zone();
    }

    /
    /**
     * @return Banner
     */
    public function getBanner(): Banner
    {
        return $this->banner;
    }

    /**
     * @return Zone
     */
    public function getZone(): Zone
    {
        return $this->zone;
    }
}
```

Which solution is better? Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Tbh, it's probably personal preference. Mine would be option 2 I reckon.

Comment: Another approach would be to set them in the Controller before passing the model to the Form. i.e. `__construct(Banner $banner, Zone $zone)` Honestly though, it boils down to which method *you* prefer and which best suits your application development requirements. For me If the relationship on `getBanner` is `DELETE CASCADE` then I would force the return requirement, otherwise if it is `DELETE SET NULL`, then I would expect a return of `NULL`. As your application is going to be dependant on the Entity getters, not just in the Forms.

Comment: You can't use option 2 because you can quickly have to initialize all your entity with empty values. As I said, in my comment below, option 1 is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think option 1 (return null) so that zone and banner records aren't created in the database if they're not necessary.

Comment: +1 ! Option 1 is definitely the way to go. When you generate an entity with the MakerBundle we can see that it is the way it generate it, mainly for this kind of issues with manipuling your new entities with the form component.